# Does the definition of eigenvalues work for non-injective linear maps?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this result that says:

> Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation and let $I$ be the Identity map ($I(v)=v$), then $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ iff $T-\alpha I$ is not one to one.

My question is does this result hold even if $T$ was not a one to one linear transformation.

Comment: Yes, it does. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not need $T$ being one-to-one, note that
\begin{align*}
  \text{$\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $T$} &\iff \exists v \in V -\{0\}: Tv = \alpha v \\
  &\iff \exists v \in V-\{0\}: (T - \alpha I)v = 0\\
  &\iff \exists v \in \ker (T -\alpha I) - \{0\} \\
  &\iff \text{$T - \alpha I$ is not one-to-one}  
\end{align*}
Note that we only used that $T$ is a linear operator, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less the definition of an eigenvalue (either it is just that, or something directly equivalent to it), so yes, it applies always. Note that by this definition one has: $T$ fails to be injective (one-to-one) if and only if $0$ is an eigenvalue of$~T$. The statements "$\alpha$ is an eigenvalue" and "$0$ is an eigenvalue" are only related when $\alpha=0$.